# multi-threads and reading a file

Tags: c, multithreading, file

I write a `C` code that reads a file and do some works on it, using multi-threads functions. I read file in the `fun1` so I expect that file read linearly, but some tests I do on this code show me that it seems that the file does not read in the right order. What is wrong about my code?!

```
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024*10
#define NUM_THREADS 4

typedef struct _thread_data_t {
  unsigned char id;
  char *msg;
  unsigned int msg_len;
} thread_data_t;

/* thread function */
void *thr_func(void *arg) {
  thread_data_t *data = (thread_data_t *)arg;
  fun2(data->msg, data->msg_len);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void fun1(FILE *file) {
    unsigned char i, j, buf[BUFSIZE];
        pthread_t thr[NUM_THREADS];
        thread_data_t thr_data[NUM_THREADS];
        int rc, fr, fd = fileno(file);               
        for (;;) {
            for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
                fr = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZE);
                if (fr <= 0) break;
                thr_data[i].id = i;
                thr_data[i].msg = buf;
                thr_data[i].msg_len = fr;
                if ((rc = pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, thr_func, &thr_data[i]))) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);
                    fr = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }    
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                pthread_join(thr[j], NULL);
            } 

            if (fr <= 0) break;
        }

}
```

Edit:
I think that until all threads finish their works nothing new read from the file. Is it true?

Comment: What is `thread_data_t` ? What is `fun2` ?

Comment: Why do you think it's not reading in the right order?   You have to provide some sort of output to show that.. and what is fun2?

Comment: I'll take a guess that you are thinking your threads will finish in the order they are started, and that is simply wrong.   There is no such guarantee.

Comment: ..or even that they'll begin running in the order they were created.  That's not guaranteed either.

Comment: `fun2` is a complex function that works on the strings read from file. I guess that until all threads finish their works nothing new read from the file.

Comment: @user57 you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: @user57 there is no guarantee that anything will or won't be read from the file before or after other threads have started or completed.   The only guarantee would be that (assuming your code is correct), that eventually all the data will be read and processed..

Comment: You will start up to NUM_THREADS and then wait for NUM_THREADS to finish before potentially starting up to NUM_THREADS again, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the single buffer:

```
buf[BUFSIZE];
```

In each loop you read data into that buffer and then prepare data for the thread

```
thr_data[i].msg = buf;
```

which I assume doesn't include a copy of the buffer itself. I assume `msg` is just a pointer.

So in the next iteration, you'll overwrite the `buf` with new data from the file and consequently change data for already created threads.

I guess you'll need

```
buf[NUM_THREADS][BUFSIZE];
```

so that each thread gets its own data area to work on.

Quote:

> I think that until all threads finish their works nothing new read from the file. Is it true?

Correct, that's what `pthread_join` does for you

Comment: Thank you! You found the problem.